# Why Qt Creator 4.10.2 (Community) by defaul doesn't install a Qt version?

Tags: qt

I've downloaded Qt5.12 creator then when I ma trying to install on windows 7 I get the default options where no version of Qt is selected then it finishes installing. But when I try to create a project it says "No valid kits found".

If I try to reinstall it and check the version for example: "5.12.6" then I see the required space is very big: 45 GB.

So please help me. My Qt creator is `Qt Creator 4.10.2 (Community)`. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? Why do you need help? And please fix your spelling, it's hard to understand what you're writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QtCreator` is a code editor/development environment. You need to also install one (or more) of the actual Qt library versions, the ones that have "very big" space requirements -- but you do not need to select the whole version tree (eg. everything in 5.12.6 branch), only the part(s) you actually need and which match the compiler you want to use (MSVC or MinGW, 32bit or 64bit).

https://www.ics.com/blog/getting-started-qt-and-qt-creator-windows